# Intellij - Remove Preedf and scala autoimport in the IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I would like to add both `-Yno-predef` and `-Yno-imports` to my scalac compilation option to my current project.

I would like Intellij help me to apply these rules to my project, but I can not benefit from the import popup as Inttelij considers that `scala._` and `scala.Predef` are auto-imported in every file.

I have tried to add `scala`, `scala.*`, `scala._` and `scala.Predef` to `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto import` to the `Exclude from import and Compilation` list, with no effect.

Thanks for your help